# TypeError: Dropzone is not a constructor

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, dropzone.js, dropzone

I've installed Dropzone.js using Composer on my Laravel 8 project
with the Metronic template.

For some reason it doesn't work.

The web developer tools console is stating that 'dropzone is not a constructor'

Here is the JS

```
const id = "#dropzones";
const dropzone = document.querySelector(id);

var myDropzone = new Dropzone(id, {

    url: "https://localhost.com/scripts/void.php",
    parallelUploads: 1,
    maxFilesize: 30, 
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    // previewsContainer: id + " .dropzone-items", // Define the container to display the previews
    clickable: id + " .dropzone-select", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
});
```

...and here is the html code

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="dropzones">
      <a class="dropzone-select btn btn-light-primary font-weight-bold btn-sm float-right" id="upload_file" type="file" >Attach File</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and for some reason it work when i use the stand alone script on the top

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ "other script") }}"></script>
```

**Is there any way to use it using Composer installation not the stand alone script?**

Comment: "_I'am installing dropzone js using composer_" Where/how did you find a composer package for dropzone.js? composer is usually used for PHP packages, not for frontend libraries. Use `npm` or `yarn` to install dropzone

Comment: https://docs.dropzone.dev/getting-started/installation/composer, im just directly install using composer install on my laravel @brombeer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative way for initialising dropzone is

```
$("#dropzones").dropzone({
    url: "https://localhost.com/scripts/void.php",
    parallelUploads: 1,
    maxFilesize: 30, 
    autoProcessQueue: false,
   // previewsContainer: id + " .dropzone-items", // Define the container to display the previews
   clickable: id + " .dropzone-select", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
 });
```

Try this way also

Comment: i used this before, but like this $("#dropzones").dropzone(id,{url:option,}); and it doesnt work but without id it working, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Glad to hear. Happy Coding :)